# Unable to call 32-bit unmanaged DLL from 64-bit managed code

Tags: vb.net, com, ipc

I have a 64-bit VB.Net application which needs to use a 3rd party 32-bit unmanaged DLL.

Here are the things I've tried:

1. I created a 32-bit vb.net wrapper class library, called COM1, and added a VB.Net COM class that calls the 32-bit unmanaged dll's exposed functions.
   The project had "Register for COM interop" enabled.
   When I referenced the 32-bit DLL (COM1.dll) to my 64-bit application and executed the application, I received the following exception:

   > Could not load file or assembly 'COM1.dll'...An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
2. I created a 64-bit vb.net wrapper class library, called COM2, and added a VB.Net COM class that calls the 32-bit unmanaged dll.
   The project had "Register for COM interop" enabled.
   When I referenced the 64-bit DLL (COM2.dll) in my 64-bit application and executed the application, I was able to load the 64-bit dll but I received the following exception when I called one of the functions exposed in the unmanaged dll (via the 64-bit wrapper dll):

   > An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
3. I tried the above steps using a WCF application as well where I replace the COM wrapper with the WCF service, but I get the same result.

I understand that I cannot call a 32-bit dll directly from my 64-bit application. What I am trying to do is call the 32-bit dll through the IPC mechanism — in this case COM or WCF. Obviously, I am making some mistake here.

Can someone give me a working code or tell me what am I doing incorrect in the above-mentioned steps?

---

Part of my code:

1. My COM class

   ```
   <ComClass(ComClass1.ClassId, ComClass1.InterfaceId, ComClass1.EventsId)> _
   Public Class ComClass1
       Public Declare Sub InitializePort Lib "I2CDrvrs" (ByVal I2cAddr As Byte, ByVal evalBoardUsed As Byte)

   #Region "COM GUIDs"
       ' These  GUIDs provide the COM identity for this class 
       ' and its COM interfaces. If you change them, existing 
       ' clients will no longer be able to access the class.
       Public Const ClassId As String = "5da6d3a4-848c-42b1-bc7c-4079ec5457b1"
       Public Const InterfaceId As String = "8de9508b-fda6-496e-bb29-a90dc5282d2c"
       Public Const EventsId As String = "cfec40ff-fec0-4250-9d72-9d63f1e37d21"
   #End Region

       ' A creatable COM class must have a Public Sub New() 
       ' with no parameters, otherwise, the class will not be 
       ' registered in the COM registry and cannot be created 
       ' via CreateObject.
       Public Sub New()
           MyBase.New()
       End Sub
   End Class
   ```
2. My 64-bit application

   ```
   Public Function foo() As Boolean
       Try
           COM1.ComClass1.InitializePort(2, 2)
       Catch ex As Exception
           MsgBox(ex.ToString)
       End Try
       Return True
   End Function
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a rather simple solution to my problem.
I implemented a client-server model using Socket Class' methods and properties.
I start a 32-bit managed-service code working as the server. The server calls the functions of 32-bit unmanaged dll. So in a way the server acts as a wrapper for the unmanaged dll.
I use my 64-bit application as client.
I pass a string to the server from my client.
The string contains information on the function to be called and its arguments.
I parse the string in server and  call the appropriate function in the unmanaged dll.

Answer (score 1):

Bringing in a COM DLL as an intermediary (be it 32-bit or 64-bit) doesn't solve the problem. You are still trying to load that 32-bit library into your 64-bit process. No amount of COM trickery will fix that.

The 32-bit library must run from inside a 32-bit process, and communicate with your 64-bit program via [*insert your inter-process method of choice here*].

You can use COM as an intermediary, sure; that's not a bad idea. But that COM intermediary must be an out-of-process server (an EXE), not a DLL.

A quick way to accomplish that is to install your COM helper as a COM+ (Component Services) application. Compile it as "32-bit", not "AnyCPU". Make sure it's installed as a "Server" not as a "Library". COM+ will provide a 32-bit host process for it.

Whether you can afford the overhead of running a library that was intended to be run in-process through an out-of-process host, I don't know. It will depend on what the library does. In some case, it might simply be impossible (e.g libraries that operate on process-affine resources).

If the DLL must run in-process within your program, then you only have two choices: a) Your program will have to compiled as 32-bit. Or, b) you have to procure a 64-bit version of the library.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I was able to create a COM+ server. I imported my 32-bit .NET wrapper to the Component Services and in the "Running Processes" pane, i can see my service (installed as server). But I am not sure how do I reference it to my 64-bit application.

Comment: You reference it the same way as before. COM takes care of the differences.

Comment: I added the 32-bit dll as reference. But I still get "BadImageFormat Exception". It appears I am trying to directly call the dll through my application somehow. Is there any property I need to set of the COM service?

Comment: Did you make sure that you set it as a Server Application? (go to Component Services\Computers\My Computer\COM+ Applications, right-click on your app's icon; Properties, "Activation" tab, under "Activation type", set it to "Server application" instead of "Library application"). That's the key to run the library in a separate 32-bit process.

Comment: Thanks for being patient, Euro. I still can't get my application running.
Following is the sequence of steps I performed:
1. Created a x86 Class library - COM_1.
2. Added a COM Class file to it - "ComClass1".
3. Declared my 32-bit unmanaged dll function as public.
4. Compiled the Class Library project.
5. In the Component Services > My Computer> COM+ Applications> New Application > Create an Empty Application > "PartestCOM" named Server Application > Interactive User Control > Roles as "CreateOwner" > Finish.

Comment: 6. In COM+ Applications> PartestCOM > Components > New Component > Import component(s) that are already registered > (select 32-bit registry so I can see the assembly name "COM_1.ComClass1") COM_1.ComClass1 > Finish.
7. PartestCOM > Start
8. I can see the com service PartestCOM running in the "Running Processes" pane. 
9. In my 64-bit application, I add the 32-bit dll - COM_1.dll.
10. When I execute the 64-bit application, I get the same exception - "Could not load file or assembly 'COM_1...An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format."

Where am I going wrong?